# Not understanding the technique of flipping

Tags: algorithm, swap

I am trying to solve an acm problem called [Stack of Flapjacks](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=56). But unfortunately I failed to understand the question. So I tried Google and found [a better explanation](http://ojreport.blogspot.com/2013/06/uva-120.html?showComment=1425827666032). This explanation says to **flip(k)**. But I don't know how to do it. Somebody please explain this for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant stuff from your original ACM problem:

> A flip consists of inserting a spatula between two pancakes in a stack and flipping (reversing) the pancakes on the spatula (reversing the sub-stack). A flip is specified by giving the position of the pancake on the bottom of the sub-stack to be flipped (relative to the whole stack). The pancake on the bottom of the whole stack has position 1 and the pancake on the top of a stack of n pancakes has position n.

flip(k) means reversing the order of pancakes from 1..k. Part of the problem is figuring out how to do it!

Using the example from the problem, let's say you implemented the stack of pancakes like this:

```
int[] pancakes = [8, 4, 6, 7, 5, 2];
```

The flip operation might be written like this:

```
int flip(int pos) {
    int spare;
    for (int i = 1; i < pos/2; i++) {
        // swap element [i] with element [pos-i+1]
        spare = pancakes[i];
        pancakes[i] = pancakes[pos-i+1];
        pancakes[pos-i+1] = spare;
    }
}
```

flip(3) would swap [1] and [3] only, [2] stays in place 
flip(4) would swap [1] and [4] then swap [2] and [3]